# Rails 3, has_one belongs_to issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a model called User with:

```
has_one :etho
```

And a model called Etho with:

```
belongs_to :user
```

I've got a build on the create method in User:

```
@user.build_etho
```

And for some reason when I login, I am still able to create more than 1 etho! A user should only have 1 etho and shouldn't be able to create any more than 1! Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what build_etho does - according to the documentation

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

"build_association(attributes = {})
Returns a new object of the associated type that has been instantiated with attributes and linked to this object through a foreign key, but has not yet been saved."

that is, each time you call build_etho, a new Etho object is created (build, that is, not saved in the db yet) - a user will always be linked to exactly one, probably the last created, but calling build_etho will not guarantee that only one is created from your User object!

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: How a user can only have 1 settings, I am attempting to make it so a user can only have 1 etho. Not sure if I know correctly how to do this. I want to make it so as a user, they've already got an etho (1 only) and they will then update it. No creation on their part.

Comment: Before you call `@user.build_etho` first check if etho already associated(exists?) like `if @user.etho.nil? @user.build_etho end` If it it created already, skip building the associated entity

Answer (score 0):

Your reference `id` column should be in your `users` table, can you confirm please?

Which means that in your users migration you should have

```
t.references :ethos
```